# How can I hide certain divs with a button on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am looking to find a way to hide a certain number of divs by using a button onclick event.

I understand that it will probably have something to do with `.toggleClass('.AddCSSClassHere')` but I am not really sure... i can do a hide/show of one div but not specific divs within a parent div. The jquery is from a previous code snippet that I was looking to use.
all the divs with the hidethis class "" need to be shown or hidden when clicking on the show columns button

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('div').toggleClass('hidethis ');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Myriad-Pro, Arial, 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.quotation {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.header-div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.titles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.currencyinfo {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.info {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.currency {
  max-width: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
}

.table-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main-div-info {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.hidethis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<section class="quotation">

  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="currencyinfo product-title">
          <button class="show-this-data">show columns</button>
        </div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis" style="border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd;">Local</div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="info product-title">Product name</div>
        <div class="info">ID</div>
        <div class="info">Quantity</div>
        <div class="info">Periods</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Price</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Cost</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Discount</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="info product-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down rotate" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">Full Throttle</a></div>
        <div class="info">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="info">1.0</div>
        <div class="info">1.0</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">USD</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">37.50</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">0.0</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">0.0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have `.siblings('ul')`, but there don't appear to be any `<ul>` elements in your HTML? In fact, the only button element in the HTML doesn't appear to have any siblings?

Comment: There's also no `active` class in your css.   Maybe it's from a library, but you don't have the library css in your HTML.

Comment: But otherwise: your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to go up a level to find the target element as a sibling. Indenting the contents of block-level elements helps visualize better.

If you want to toggle all such elements in all containers, you'll need to either introduce a new class to keep track of them when the class is removed, or select them all once and use that list of elements.

```js
$(function() {
  const elsToToggle = $('.hidethis');

  $('.show-this-data').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div').toggleClass('hidethis ');
  });

  $('.show-all-data').click(function() {
    elsToToggle.toggleClass('hidethis');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Myriad-Pro, Arial, 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.quotation {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.header-div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.titles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.currencyinfo {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.info {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.currency {
  max-width: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
}

.table-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main-div-info {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.hidethis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<section class="quotation">

  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="currencyinfo product-title">
          <button class="show-this-data">show columns in this block</button>
          <button class="show-all-data">show columns in all blocks</button>
        </div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis" style="border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd;">Local</div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
        <div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="info product-title">Product name</div>
        <div class="info">ID</div>
        <div class="info">Quantity</div>
        <div class="info">Periods</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Price</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Cost</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">Unit Discount</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class="titles">
        <div class="info product-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down rotate" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">Full Throttle</a></div>
        <div class="info">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="info">1.0</div>
        <div class="info">1.0</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">USD</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">37.50</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">0.0</div>
        <div class="info hidethis">0.0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for that, i have added it to my code, was just wondering how you would also show/hide all the divs with the .hidethis class with the button click

Comment: all the divs with the hidethis class
"<div class="currencyinfo hidethis"></div>"

need to be shown or hidden when clicking on the <button class="show-this-data">show columns</button> button

Comment: Answer updated. Again, you need to _update your question_ to better reflect this request.